# Perform MAD calculation on two different columns of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Sample Data

```
date = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
subproduct=rep("x",48)
actuals <- c(seq(1:29),rep(0,19))
m1 <- c(rep(0,24),seq(1:24))
m2<- c(rep(0,24),rep(10,24))
dfone <- data.frame(date,
                subproduct,
                actuals,m1,m2)

      date subproduct actuals m1 m2
```

Here is row 24-30 for the dfone

```
 date           subproduct  actuals m1 m2
24 2020-12-01          x      24  0  0
25 2021-01-01          x      25  1 10
26 2021-02-01          x      26  2 10
27 2021-03-01          x      27  3 10
28 2021-04-01          x      28  4 10
29 2021-05-01          x      29  5 10
30 2021-06-01          x       0  6 10
```

What I want to do is apply this formula onto row where there is numbers not 0 in all three columns (row 25-29) I want to take actuals at row 25

```
m1abs1 <- abs(25-1)
m1abs2<- abs(26-2)
m1abs3 <- abs(27-3)
m1abs4 <- abs(28-4)
m1abs5 <- abs(29-5)

m1MAD <- sum(m1abs1,m1abs2,m1abs3,m1abs4,m1abs5)/5
# 24

m2abs1 <- abs(25-10)
m2abs2<- abs(26-10)
m2abs3 <- abs(27-10)
m2abs4 <- abs(28-10)
m2abs5 <- abs(29-10)

m2MAD <- sum(m2abs1,m2abs2,m2abs3,m2abs4,m2abs5)/5
# 17

max(m1MAD,m2MAD)
```

Now that we have max, remove the column from dataframe that isn't the max so m2MAD in this case.

## Question: Is there a way to do this in R more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `if_all` to `filter` the rows where there are no zeros in those columns, then `summarise` to return the `max` of `mean` of `abs`olute deviations

```
library(dplyr)
dfone %>% 
    filter(if_all(actuals:m2, ~ . != 0)) %>% 
    summarise(MADmax = max(mean(abs(actuals - m1)), 
          mean(abs(actuals - m2))))
```

-output

```
   MADmax
1     24
```

---

If we want to remove the column which is not the `max`

```
dfone %>% 
     filter(if_all(actuals:m2, ~ . != 0)) %>% 
     summarise(nm1 = c('m1', 'm2')[which.max(c(mean(abs(actuals - m1)), 
           mean(abs(actuals - m2))))]) %>%
      pull(nm1) %>% setdiff(names(dfone), .) -> tmp
dftwo <- dfone %>%
    select(all_of(tmp))
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
dfone %>% 
   filter(if_all(c(actuals, matches('^m\\d+')), ~ . != 0))  %>% 
   summarise(across(matches('^m\\d+'), ~ mean(abs(actuals - .)))) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
   filter(value != max(value)) %$% 
   select(dfone, -all_of(name))
```

---

Or using `base R` with `subset` and `rowSums` to create a logical vector to subset and get the `max` of 'MAD'

```
with(subset(dfone, !rowSums(dfone[c('actuals', 'm1', 'm2')] == 0)), 
       max(mean(abs(actuals - m1)), 
           mean(abs(actuals - m2))))
[1] 24
```

Comment: Will test this! One second

Comment: @chriswang123456 i updated with the second part of the question i.e to remove the ones that are not max

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you.  If I have a lot of columns like m1,m2,m3,.... up to m100, is there an easy way to retrieve them without typing them out? Also a second thing, if i have to compare m1...m5 and c1...c5 seperately, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @chriswang123456 the solution with `pivot_longer` does that automatically i.e. you can change `actuals:m2` to `if_all(c(actuals, matches('^m\\d+$'))`

Comment: @chriswang123456 updated for the m1 to m100 case.  Regarding the second case if you want to do it separately change the matches to `matches('^c\\d+$')`

Comment: Yeah okay, this works perfect. Thank you, genius as always!

Comment: Oh one more question, how is matches() formatted? If I had something like m1_a how would i write that? Is it regex?

Comment: @chriswang123456 then you can change the regex to `matches('^m\\d+_\\w+$')` or `^m\\d+_[a-z]+$`

Comment: I had an additional question, if I had lets say 10 different unique subproducts, how would I use this code to keep the columns with max value for each subproduct? This would mean there could be a max of 10 columns kept but the minimum is 1. I can ask it in a new question if you'd like

Comment: @chriswang123456 if you have 10 different cases, either you can loop over with those matches using `map` and get those separately in a loop or perhaps use `pivot_longer` if the patterns are kind of similar